# How to add chapter description in latex

Tags: sectioning, chapters

I want to add a chapter description after for example,

> Chapter 1
>
> Chapter Name
>
> Here goes long description (the size and font type should be the same
>   as document

I am using Book environment and this code

```
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
  {\textbf\sffamily\huge\bfseries}
  {\chaptertitlename\ \thechapter}{5pt}
  {\begin{flushleft}
  \normalfont\normalsize\itshape\ChapterDesc \vspace{0.25cm}
  \end{flushleft}
  \Huge}
\newcommand\ChapterDesc{}
```

I have also tried this solution of [TorbjornT](https://gist.github.com/TorbjornT/30912a162bb5b00a473dbb4773014cfc)[image: This is current situation]

Thank you in advance :)

Comment: Welcome! What would be the specifications? More or less like the `abstract` environment?

Comment: Hello Bernard! yes exactly.

Comment: Try  to do that with the `quoting` package, which supplies tools to customise quotes.

Comment: can you please elaborate yourself? i am at ametuer level of latex. ty

Comment: Which class do you use?

Comment: if you meant documentclass, then my answer is book. ty

Comment: @Mannie: If I understand your question correctly, you could simply add text after the chapter and before starting the first section. I don‘t really get why an extra environment is necessary for this, especially considering that you want the text to look like the rest of the document.  Or is there a problem that I missed?

Comment: no, you understood me right.. I thought there is a requirement of new environment... ty but.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `memoir` class (a superset of the `book`, `report` and `article` classes.

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\tableofcontents
\mainmatter
\chapter{First}
\chapterprecis{This is a precis of the first chapter.}
Lots of text
\end{document}
```

Read the documentation (`texdoc memoir`) for how to get `\chapterprecis` to fit your needs.

Comment: Hello, Peter Wilson. your solution did changes the way I wanted, but there are problems that arose among them, I need to change page numbering style because my title page took roman page number 'i'. I think i need to go through the document you suggested. ty for your answer.

Comment: @Mannie The `\frontmatter` command sets page numbers to be roman and `\mainmatter` sets page numbers to arabic. Did you use these in your `book` class document? If not then don't use them in `memoir`, but you should consider using them, and also `\backmatter` for the bibliography and index